# Azure connection string resolves to 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have a .NET Core 3.1 application that when debugging it on local machine cannot connect to the database.

The connection string looks like this (with obvious replacement of values)

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:thedbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=theDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

But when running this on my machine I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'theDatabase' on server '127.0.0.1'.

Why does it try to connect on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Do you have `thedbserver.database.windows.net` in your local hosts file?

Comment: you might have another appsettings, for example appsettings.development.json with a different connection string, and your applications could be using development file while debugging locally

Comment: Of course, stupid me. You were right @Nouman. there was an expand-arrow on the appSettings hiding the development appSettings. Feel so noob. Answer that and I can accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I once spent an hour trying to figure out this issue after we introduced ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in one of our dev server and application started using appsettings.development.json instead of appsettings.json which it was using before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging; your application might be using *appsettings.development.json* instead of *appsettings.json* which could have a connection string pointing to 127.0.0.1

> *appsettings.**Environment**.json* values override keys in *appsettings.json*

[Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)